# How to return a message without raising an error

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-fullstack

I have an issue where I need a function to run all the way through without an error but also needs to be able to create a message for the front end.

It goes like this:

```py
def loginUser():
    user = user.getUser()
    user_is_gone = user.date 
    
    if user_is_gone != Null:
        raise Unauthorized(f"Done")
    
    validation_of_user(validate, user)

    response = auth_service.auth_user(
        user=user, pass=pass
    )
```

On the front end I have this:

```js
if (e.response.data.message === Done && user.loginUser) {
    
    toast.error(
        'You are no longer able to perform this action'
    );
    setLoading(false);
    return;
}
```

How can I return something I can use like `data.message` with actually failing jumping out of the function? I need to pass me a message and run all the way through.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but have you considered using the  try-except block for managing exceptions? Also if you raise an exception like Unauthorized, it should be handled somewhere.

Comment: Can you tell which error it is ? Is it arising from the front or back end ? Don't hesitate to put as much detail as you have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to squelch the exception like so:

```py
def falliable(denominator):
    try:
        # A default value in case an error is raised prior to ZeroDivisionError.
        # This can't occur in my snippet but is a good practice because the return
        # value always exists.
        result = "Incomplete"
        print("Doin' stuff")

        # Possibly raises ZeroDivisionError
        crazy_calculation = 1/denominator
        result = f"Success: {crazy_calculation}"
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # ZeroDivisionError is consumed but not bubbled up the stack.
        # Set result to an error message.
        result = f"Oops, 1/{denominator}!"
    finally:
        # Perform any tasks not reliant on crazy_calculation's success and return the message.
        print("Doin' other stuff")
        return result

ok = falliable(14)
err = falliable(0)

print(f"{ok}\n{err}")
```

Prints:

```
Doin' stuff
Doin' other stuff
Doin' stuff
Doin' other stuff
Success: 0.07142857142857142
Oops, 1/0!
```

`ZeroDivisionError` is caught but not bubbled up which allows the rest of the code to continue. `result` stores a message based on the success or failure of the operation.